# How to calculate buildings shadow areas

Tags: dem, elevation, algorithm, remote-sensing, terrain

Is it possible to calculate shadow areas of buildings or simulate shadows of buildings in a city using e-cognition software, with the DSM of the buildings and the sun angle and azimuth known?....If not, could you please tell me the software that can do this work.